# Where can I find information about "Enhanced Policies and Procedures Exam" for IPC?

Tags: standard, test, certification, education, ipc

I'm taking the CSE test for IPC-J-STD-001 and at chapter **7.Certification Exam Overview**, I can see that there are 3 types of tests.

- Policy and procedure test (10 questions)
- Closed book test (25 questions)
- Open book test (75 questions)

Inside IPC's document they write:

**7.Enhanced Policies and Procedures Exam**

The Enhanced Policies and Procedures Exam contains 10 multiple-choice questions that
evaluate a candidate’s understanding of:

- a) The Policies and Procedures for the certification program that the candidate is
  attempting to complete.
- b) The history of the electronics industry and how standards help improve the industry.
- c) The key steps in the production of a circuit board and electronics assembly.
- d) How standards are developed, revised, and documented, and how you can help improve
  those standards.
- e) How to apply standards certification to increase the quality for your company, your
  customers, and the electronics industry.
- f) How to get assistance in solving your technical challenges.

So preparing for the Policy and Procedure exam, I want to find information about these topics. For a) I have found these at chapter **2.About the Policies and Procedures**

Source for finding the chapters: https://www.ipc.org/ipc-certification-policies-procedures

For b) I have found how a standard can improve the indistry. I have not found any source about history about eletronic manufacturing.

https://www.ipc.org/why-electronics-manufacturers-need-ipc-standards

For c) I have found the key steps for start to finish for manufacturing a PCB board. It's the same link above, but this URL link also shows a flow chart of the production.

https://www.ipc.org/why-electronics-manufacturers-need-ipc-standards

**Question:**

If I want to find information about the rest of the topics from IPC's page. Where should I do the search then? I find no information about history about eletronics at IPC's page, only history about IPC and how they were founded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer.

All information can be found in the Policy and Procedure document...but...

1. It's 15 questions. Not 10 questions.
2. It's only questions about the CIS certification. No question about CSE certification
3. No question about IPC, history, how to get assistance in solving your technical challenges, how to apply standards certification, how standards are developed etc. 0% questions about that!
4. No time limit on the test.
5. No proctoring exam. Nothing! Just a simple quiz with really confusing questions.
6. For the CSE J-STD-001H standard, you need to have CIS J-STD-001G policy and procedure document from 2019.

So IPC have made something terrible wrong. But I have received my CSE in J-STD-001 anyway!

The closed book test (20 questions, 1 hour) is ONLY about chapter 1 in the J-STD-001 book. Only chapter 1 and you need to know EVERYTHING in chapter 1. They can ask you about anything e.g a word, a scentence or a number.

The open book test (70-questions, 2.5 hours) is chapter 2 and above. Mostly wires, PCB, SMD, through hole assemblies, coating, adhesive and cleaning. So all chapters except chapter 1. It can happen that you might get a question from chapter 1, but that's only 1 or 2 questions. The main questions comes from chapter 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

You get 2.14 minutes per question for the open book test. So make sure that you are familiar with every page of the book and know exactly where to find information.